# How to add AJAX Submit to PHP validation and return message?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I've been working my way up on validating a form and got the JS and PHP validation to work but I am still having a hard time adding ajax(with or without JQUERY) to submit to the php file and return a success message.

My form with CSS and JS validation:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#nameerror {
color:red;
}
#emailerror{
color:red;
}
</style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function Validate()  {

var email = document.forms['form']['email'].value;
var atpos = email.indexOf('@');
var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf('.');
var name = document.forms['form']['name'].value;

if (name == null || name == ""){
document.getElementById('nameerror').innerHTML="Please enter your name";
return false;
} else if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos+2 || dotpos+2 >= email.length) {

document.getElementById('emailerror').innerHTML="Please enter a valid email";
return false;
} else {

}   
}

</script>


</head>
<body>
<div>Sign Up</div>
    <form name="form" action="form_validation.php" id="form" onsubmit="return Validate();" method = 'post'> 
<label>Name:</label><br/>
<input id='name' type="text" name='name' /><br/>
<span id="nameerror"></span><br/>
<label>Email:</label><br/>
<input type='text' name='email' id = 'email'/> <br/>
<span id= "emailerror"></span><br/>
<label>Comments:</label><br/>
<textarea name='comments' id ='comments'></textarea><br/>
<span id="comerror"></span>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>  
<span id="success" style="display:none">Your message has been sent successfully.</span>

</form>  
</body>
</html>
```

And this is form_validation.php:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if($_POST['name']){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
}
if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/', $name)){
    echo "Name can only contain letters.";
    return false;
} else {
        echo "Name accepted";
}   

if($_POST['email']){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
}
$pattern = '/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/';
if(!preg_match($pattern, $email)){
    echo "Please enter a valid email address.";
    return false;
} else {
    echo "Email Valid";
}
if($_POST['comments']){
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];     
}
if (strlen($comments) > 100){
    echo "please enter less than 100 characters.";
    return false;
} 
}

?>
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: there's a big hole where you need code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').on('submit',function() {

$.ajax({
       url: 'form_validation.php',
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       type: 'POST'
            }).done(function(data){

                  // you can append a success message to your document here

            });


                                  });
```

Comment: I've added it to my code with a success message to display in a span tag but all it does is reroute to my form_validation.php. How can I just stay on the form page?